# Creating monthly total counts and monthly counts filtered by entry type in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been stuck on this for a couple sittings now and figured it might be more time efficient to ask. The answer is likely something relatively simple I'm not aware of as this seems like a common task, though I could find no similar online examples.

On a list of activities people have done, I am trying to get a condensed activity count list, as group_by(Person) %>% summarise() would be used for, for each person. I am trying to achieve the following end result:

1 person per row

Columns (for each person):

-Total activities

-Total for each type

-Total for each subtype *(tallying combinations of types + subtypes doesn't matter fyi)*

-Total count for each month (so each month is a column)

-Total type count for each month *(12 mos X 2 Types = 24 more columns)*

-total subtype count for each month *(12 mos X 3 subtypes = 36 more columns)*

If there is no count for a month (as there isn't for July-December in the example), it needs to read 0 ie the month isn't excluded.

```
activities <- data.frame(
  Person = c(rep("Person A", 3), rep("Person B", 3)), 
  Month = seq(as.Date("2020/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 6),
  Activity.Type = as.factor(seq(1:2)),
  Activity.Sub.Type = as.factor(seq(1:3))
  )
activities
```

All of the month columns may seem odd, but I'm adding this data to an annual productivity metric for each person for a regression model. This seemed like the best way to structure everything for that use case.

Let me know if you have any questions and thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need `activities %>% group_by(Person) %>% summarise(across(where(is.factor), nlevels), n = n())`

Comment: Are you sure you want one row per person? When you say *"If there is no count for a month (as there isn't for July-December in the example), it needs to read 0 ie the month isn't excluded."* it sounds like you want one row per person per month., and you would need to `group_by` both Person and Month.

Comment: Thanks a ton both! activities %>% group_by(Person) %>% summarise(across(where(is.factor), nlevels), n = n()) seems to produce a tally of the number of unique activity types per person, as opposed to counts for each activity type. This isn't a requirement of the question. Gregor: That makes sense, you may be onto something. In that case I am still unsure how to get a row for months in which there are no activities e.g. July-December in the example.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the data but it is really helpful if you also share the expected output along with it so that we can compare our answers to them and provide you exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure. But maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_month <- activities %>% 
    group_by(Person, Month) %>% 
    add_count() %>% 
    add_count(Activity.Type) %>% 
    add_count(Activity.Sub.Type) %>% 
    summarise(Total_activites = sum(n), Activity.Type=sum(nn), Activity.Sub.Type=sum(nnn)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = Month, 
        values_from = Total_activites:Activity.Sub.Type
    )

activities %>% 
    group_by(Person) %>% 
    add_count() %>% 
    add_count(Activity.Type) %>% 
    add_count(Activity.Sub.Type) %>% 
    summarise(Total_activites = sum(n), Activity.Type=sum(nn), Activity.Sub.Type=sum(nnn)) %>% 
    right_join(df_month, by="Person")
```

```
Person   Total_activites Activity.Type Activity.Sub.Type `Total_activite~ `Total_activite~ `Total_activite~ `Total_activite~ `Total_activite~ `Total_activite~
  <chr>              <int>         <int>             <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>
1 Person A               9             5                 3                1                1                1               NA               NA               NA
2 Person B               9             5                 3               NA               NA               NA                1                1                1
# ... with 12 more variables: Activity.Type_2020-01-01 <int>, Activity.Type_2020-02-01 <int>, Activity.Type_2020-03-01 <int>, Activity.Type_2020-04-01 <int>,
#   Activity.Type_2020-05-01 <int>, Activity.Type_2020-06-01 <int>, Activity.Sub.Type_2020-01-01 <int>, Activity.Sub.Type_2020-02-01 <int>,
#   Activity.Sub.Type_2020-03-01 <int>, Activity.Sub.Type_2020-04-01 <int>, Activity.Sub.Type_2020-05-01 <int>, Activity.Sub.Type_2020-06-01 <int>
```

Comment: Thanks for going through this TarJae! I think Total_Activities for Person A should be 3, same with Person B. I will play around with your answer though, I haven't used add_count() in the past and it seems fitting.